# как передать параметры в функцию?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Подскажите пожалуйста как передать данные переменных PHP в функцию javascript?

`input type='checkbox' onchange='loadXMLDoc();'`  (циклом PHP выводится большое количество данных, с разными id и т.д.)

Могу ли я как то подставить переменные в

`...onchange='loadXMLDoc(***__сюда__***);'...`

и далее отправить их

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","new.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(***___по идее сюда___***);
```

**Обновление**

```
do   
{
    printf ("
    <a href='product_page.php?id=%s&cat=%s'>
        <div id='spisok_tovarov'>
            <div id='img_spisok_tovarov'>
                <img src='%s' />
            </div>  
            <div id='price'>
                <strong>%s</strong> 
            </div>
            <div id='tekst_spisok_tovarov'>
                     %s
            </div>
            <input type='checkbox' onchange='loadXMLDoc(**%s,%s**);'>AJAX
        </div>
    </a>
" ,$myrow_t['id'], $_GET['cat'], $myrow_t['img_mini'] ,$myrow_t['price'] ,$myrow_t['description'],$sesid,$myrow_t['id']);
      }
 while ($myrow_t = mysql_fetch_array($result_t));
```

Речь идет о `$sesid` и `$myrow_t['id']`. Их нужно передать в

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// код для IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// код для IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","new.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(**СЮДА**);
}
```

На сколько я понял, переменные нужно отправить в `xmlhttp.send();`, но не совсем пойму как мне их тут определить?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вас интересует это

```
...onchange="loadXMLDoc('<?php echo $data ?>')"...
```

Способ конечно не самый лучший, но если очень хочется, то можно.

Чтобы зациклить все это дело, можно использовать следующую конструкцию прямо в HTML:

```
<?php foreach($array as $key=>$value): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" onchange"loadXMLDoc('<?php echo $value ?>')">
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не рекомендую но можно.
Я так понимаю у вас печатается html с помощью php на страницу. 
Если так то можно передать параметры в виде JSON строки.
`$jsonValue = json_encode($array);
 $html = "input type='checkbox' onchange='loadXMLDoc(".$jsonValue.");"; 
 print($html);`

на стороне js принять и разобрать как JSON.